# Vanilla JS + VueJS: Scroll to top of div on button click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an app created using VueJS. It is a multistep form with a next button.
You can view the app working here:
https://staging.evbox.com/configurator.html

The issue I am trying to solve, is once the user clicks the next button, the top of the following question is visible. Can someone help me with a vanilla JS solution or some advice?

The button html:

```
  <button class="button-container__next" type="button" @click="goToNextStep()">Next</button>
```

And the function is:

```
    goToNextStep: function () {
        this.currentStep++
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the scrollbar is for `body`. So you can do this:

```
goToNextStep: function () {
   this.currentStep++;
   window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

If the main scrollbar is not attached to the `body`, try two following lines:

```
document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For safari
document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
```

Comment: Do you want to scroll to top of content when you click on next? Am I right? @madameFerry

Comment: Yes that is correct. When the user clicks "Next" the top of the following question is hidden from view beneath the "progress" bar. This happens when the user has scrolled down to view the button. Any other ideas?

Comment: I have edited the answer as you have attached the scrollbar to the `html` tag not the `body` @madameFerry

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing the following. I found this script but I have to be honest im not really sure how it works. Can someone explain it to me?

```
goToNextStep: function () {
        this.currentStep++

        let myDiv = document.getElementById('wrapper');
        scrollTo(document.body, myDiv.offsetTop, 100);

        function scrollTo(element, to, duration) {
          if (duration < 0) return;
          var difference = to - element.scrollTop;
          var perTick = difference / duration * 2;

          setTimeout(function() {
            element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop + perTick;
            scrollTo(element, to, duration - 2);
          }, 10);
        }
      }
```

I also added this to the CSS:

```
html { height: 100%; overflow:auto!important; }
body { height: 100%!important; }
```